# How to stop .NET setup based on registry value?

Tags: .net, setup-project, registry

I set up a *Search Registry Launch Condition* in my .NET setup project. The value I'm looking for is a path of another program where I need to install as a plugin. Now, this works.

But I don't know what value is returned if it cannot find the registry key (program not installed). I need this value to create a setup condition around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around and used a *Launch Condition* in the *Requirements on Target Machine* section.

Followed the tips here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0z89y5d(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0z89y5d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)